Custom Staging Ground Comments
With the release of the Staging Ground on Stack Overflow, I want to share the userscripts I wrote for it during its Beta tests.
The Staging Ground offers some built-in comment templates but if you want to have your own templates, you can add them using this user script. I felt the need to create this user script as I wrote some things over and over.

It is conceptually similar to AutoReviewComments but for the Staging Ground.
Get it
You can view or install it on GitHub.
Here is a list of the comments I have added myself if someone wants inspiration:



Name
Text




Include Code inside question
Questions on Stack Overflow should contain everything necessary to answer them. Please [edit] your question and include the _relevant_ parts of your code using a [code block].


Include info from comments
Please [edit] your question and include that in it. When it gets published, the comments will be cleaned up so all necessary information should be present in the question itself.


multiple questions/too broad
It seems like you asked multiple questions in one. Please reduce your post to a single question.


not specific/too general
Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem you are trying to solve. It seems like your question is quite broad. When asking questions on Stack Overflow, please ask about _specific_ programming problems or similar. Questions that are too broad are [not considered on-topic on Stack Overflow](/help/on-topic).


'Why' question
See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/10871900) on why questions asking for (historical) reasoning are typically considered opinion-based on Stack Overflow. Essentially these questions are unlikely to lead to satisfying answers. People probably decided to do it that way so they did.



Note that these were written during the Beta tests of the Staging Ground so I don't know how applicable they still are. Also note that these are templates, it's often a good idea to modify them before posting.
